# Listview : enable in adapter if view is enabled

Tags: android, android-listview

My `ListView` is populate with custom cells and custom adapter.

If the cell is disabled, I want to set `isEnabled()` to false in the adapter :

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position)
{
    // if cell is disabled, return false. If not return true
}
```

But the cell don't know the adapter.
Is there a way to get the *current cell object* in the `isEnabled()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of getItem(position) and use the postition you get in the overriden method, Assuming that you have already overrided getItem in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled( int position )
{
    CellType c = cells.get( postion )
    if( c.isEnabled() ){
         return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the list you used populated as Global object. Then by using cellList.get(position) you can get the current cell.